# Should I allow multiple logins?

Tags: php, session

I suppose the answer is - "it depends on your app" ?

If I log in twice, each calls `session_start()` and I end up with two totally independent sessions. Each login is timestamped, as is each logout (log time of zer0 - set at login - indicates user is still logged in).

I have an audit trail where every new row added to a table (I never modify, to support the audit trail) has user_id and timestamp.

Question: is there any compelling reason to allow or disallow multiple logins? I thought at first to disallow, but now I don't see any real reason to do so - and allowing it means no extra code.

What's the general practise?

Comment: It depends on your...oh. Never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no danger to user security, allow multiple, but if there are any security threats, i would only use a single login. Like leaving two profiles logged into facebook at two different houses, possible, but is it safe?

Comment: I guess it depends how FB handles simultaneous attempts to update the same data. That is no problem for me  (+1 to each of you)

Answer (score 1):

The general practice is to only implement what you really need in.

You cannot justify the feature - YAGNI.

Comment: ok, which is the feature - multiple logins or preventing multiple logins?  At the moment, I don't care, but that may change. Allowing multiple logins requires no additional code, prevention does.

Comment: @Mawg: so, why to do the work that you don't need to do? When it will change - do that, not before.

Comment: +1 Not that you actually identified what "it" is, but one can infer :-)   So, multiple logins are ok until someone whinges - then I write code to prevent it. Thanks for taking the time to reply